# python repo without hosting a server

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I have put together bunch of python packages that I would like to share with my team now.

I saw bunch of articles about hosting pypi server but I would like to go around the husle of setting up a machine and getting permission to do so.

I was hoping that I could just make packages available through network write that my coworkers can access.

So one of my packages that I created has following `setup.py` script:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='prodorm',
    version='0.1',
    packages = find_packages(),
    install_requires = ['ormutils @ file://N:/some/path/']
)
```

ormutils is located at : `N:/some/path/ormutils`

but when i try to install using above script I get:

> Couldn't find index page for 'ormutils' (maybe misspelled?) Scanning
>   index of all packages (this may take a while) Reading
>   https://pypi.org/simple/ No local packages or working download links
>   found for ormutils@ file:n:/some/path/ error:
>   Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('ormutils@
>   file://n:/some/path/')

What is this 'index page' that I clearly did not create and how can I create it?

Comment: You can specify dirs for package lookup via `--find-links`, e.g. `pip install prodorm --find-links N:/some/path/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install packages using [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) that are hosted in GitHub or GitLab (or probably any git solution, web-hosted or self-hosted).

I suggest you take a look at that blog article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-github-as-a-pypi-server-1c3b0d07db2

Comment: Thanks @ggrelet probably best solution