# Local python repository, but no server

Tags: python

My question is very similar to this one:
[python repo without hosting a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840330/python-repo-without-hosting-a-server)
but the accepted answer to that one is not the solution for me as it replaces the web server with a git server.

Reading this
https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/
I see that it is very easy to create a python repository
I just have to create a correct directory structure, and run a web server which makes that directory structure available.
I want to skip the server and have a completely local repository.
I don't want to get permission to run a server on the required computer  because I will not get it.
I don't want external service.
I just want the local repository be available without the server in between.
Is there a way to specify the repository url for pip as for example "file:///d:/example-repository" or something like this?

I know that it is possible to manually install with pip a selected package file, but this is not what I want.
I want a whole repository, but offline.

*Why* I would want to have a totally offline repository and how would the packages go into it is a completely different topic, independent of this question?

Edited to add: apparently, it's not entirely clear what I mean by this.
Consider the following situation:
I develop multiple python libraries to do some stuff commonly occuring in my projects.
For example controlling some of our custom made devices over usb.
I create python packages from these libraries.
I don't upload them anywhere. They are meant to be used locally and they are anyway useless without the equipment.
Later I want to create multiple independent projects using those libraries.
Each project gets its own virtual environment. And for each I install only the packages that it needs. Including my own libraries. Likely different projects will end up using different releases of my libraries. When I update a library I don't want to propagate it to all the projects using it already, because of the risk of breaking something there.
So how I handle this?
For public packages it's easy - just install by PIP.
I can automate this by specifying requirements of projects and make pip install what I need.
But then my private packages.
I can install them from PIP too, by manually pointing pip to the package files created by me when doing the release of library.
But this is manual work.
One solution is to create my own server which will serve my libraries, and add its url to pip.
This is actually a very reasonable thing to do.
But in my case, I would like to skip the server part.
After some reading I find out that to set up my server I just need a http(s) server and a correctly prepared filesystem substructure.
Which means that the http server is unaware that it is actually serving a python repository.
Pip is doing all the work of understanding the filesystem structure.
So I thought to skip the http server and make pip read the local filesystem directly without the interface of a http server.
(It is already doing most of the work anyway)
Similarly how for example the APT (package manager for some gnu/linux distributions) can be configured to install packages from a CD-ROM instead of an internet.

So that's why I'm posting this question to find out if there is a good way of achieving this.

Comment: hmmm, interesting, what happens if you put your package in the `site-packages` directory somewhere in the python directory, would that make that package available for the python interpreter similarly as an installed package?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good list of "don't want" capabilities.  However, you're not clear on what you *do* want.  In common usage, "repository" is a data base -- of code, in your case -- that stores the data for a service -- in your case, the various actions of version control on the code.

If you want the capabilities of a service, especially if you're using a downloaded package to provide those capabilities, then you need to provide the configuration for that package.  For the two packages my devOps have discussed with me, the package is set up as a common service: one configured as a server.

As far as I know, you need to configure a local server -- that being the software abstraction that provides the service.

Comment: I edited my question to add more information to be more understandable what I mean.